# string replace underscore with open and close html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with underscores around certain words that need replacement with an open `<i>`  and close `</i>` html tags.

Heres what I have so far but this flanks the underscore itself and not the word
 `var t2= str.replace(/_/, '<i>$&</i>');`
results `<i>_</i>Lorem Ipsum<i>_</i> is simply dummy text`

What I need is `<i>Lorem Ipsum</i> is simply dummy text`
From `_Lorem Ipsum_ is simply dummy text`

How can I get this using JavaScript, regex?

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: You need `var t2 = str.replace(/_([^_]*)_/g, '<i>$1</i>');`

Comment: I did not downvote, but you could write it an a more understandable way. E.g. in the second paragraph, start with the example input text + the output that you want. Then your attempted code + what it produces (and perhaps clarification about the difference, if that is not obvious by itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```js
var str = "_Lorem Ipsum_ is simply dummy text";
var t2 = str.replace(/_([^_]*)_/g, '<i>$1</i>');  
console.log(t2);
```

**Details**

- `_` - matches an underscore
- `([^_]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore.

The replacement contains a replacement backreference, `$1`, that inserts the Group  1 value in between `<i>` and `</i>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZXawh/1).